# Hosting plugins and themes on two different servers

Tags: plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I run a full fledged social network on Wordpress, and it undoubtedly requires a lot of plugins which take up a lost of disk space on my shared hosting account. I have two websites running on Wordpress, each on a separate Godaddy account. Lets call the first one website1 and the second website2.

Website1 gets tons of traffic, which takes up a lot of memory and that coupled with the plugins running slows down and sometimes even crashes the site.

Website2 is a completely different story. I was making it for a client, but he soon lost interest in it and now it just sits there, with all the memory not even half full. So in other words, website1 is overloaded and website2 having a relaxed time.

Now what I wanted to do was to upload half (or if possible, all) of the plugins to website2 but have them show up on website1.

Is this possible? I would request some clear and helpful answers :D

And if it can be done with plugins, can it be done with themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link could be helpful for plugins and maybe there is a similar way for the theme.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74958/change-the-path-where-wordpress-plugins-are-uploaded

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically, I change the url to where the website2 is? I was wondering if you would be able to help me with this if I entrusted you with the credentials to my account?